# How well does Snowball microphone from Blue work in Ubuntu Studio 16.04.1

Tags: drivers, microphone, ubuntu-studio, audio-recording

I am planning on getting a microphone for my laptop and I have a Asus X550LA-DH71. I was looking into the Blue Tiki but it didn't seem to be good enough and it also seemed like I needed a driver. I need to know if it will work and how well.

Comment: I can't answer because I would need to test it. But I can give you some pointers. Generally USB audio devices that are "plug'n'play" in Windows also works as such in Ubuntu. Conversely, what needs additional drivers in Windows and the manufacturer doesn't provide an equivalent for Linux may work partially or not at all.

Comment: Im just trying to see about it because I'm planning on getting one this Christmas

Comment: Perhaps someone can actually answer. Meanwhile I suggest you do your own research googling your device brand/model + ubuntu. Also check what user are reporting in Windows, whether or not additional drivers are required, etc.